# Null Pointer Exception on an EditText in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am building a signUp page in which i want a date picker but whenever i click on User `Fragment` to open Sign up Page then the app crashes, and the error is `nullPointerException` in `EditText`. Please Help me to solve it.

Here is the Code of `UserFragment.java`

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment {
public EditText et_Date;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 11;
String selectedDate;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener setListener;
View view;
public UserFragment() {
}
public static UserFragment newInstance() {
    UserFragment fragment = new UserFragment();
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adduser_fragment, container, false);
    et_Date  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etdate);
    final FragmentManager fm = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
    et_Date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppCompatDialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.setTargetFragment(UserFragment.this,REQUEST_CODE);
            newFragment.show(fm, "DatePicker");
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            selectedDate = data.getStringExtra("SelectedDate");
            et_Date.setText(selectedDate);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener){
        mListener= (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    }else{
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()+"must implement OnFragmentInterationListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Comment: Show logcat errors, please.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.navigationdrawer.UserFragment.onCreateView(UserFragment.java:60)

Answer (score 0):

Your editText with id etdate is actually in layout adduser_fragment? This error may be because of view is in another layout(and you forgot that). Sorry for answer, I don't have enough reputation to post comment.

Comment: yes it is in adduser_fragment.xml. I gave etdate id to the EditText.

Comment: `findViewById` didn't find your `EditText` object. The stack trace (which would look nicer if you add it to your post; comment formatting is limited) clearly says you're invoking `setOnClickListener` on a `null` object, which in your case is `et_Date`. It would be helpful if you'd post `adduser_fragment.xml`.